# Shiny dashboard in R, produce text based on dynamic inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny dashboard that has dynamic inputs.
It prints the results of those inputs when they are entered.
I want it to print the results of those inputs when the calculate action button is pressed.
Below is my code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Inputs"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("addBtn", "Add Input"),
      uiOutput("dynamicInputs"),
      actionButton("calculate", "Calculate")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("result")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Counter for the number of inputs
  counter <- reactiveVal(1)
  
  # Generate dynamic inputs based on the counter
  output$dynamicInputs <- renderUI({
    inputList <- lapply(1:counter(), function(i) {
      textInput(inputId = paste0("input", i), label = paste("Input", i), value = "")
    })
    do.call(tagList, inputList)
  })
  
  # Increment the counter when the "Add Input" button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$addBtn, {
    counter(counter() + 1)
  })
  
  # Print the result based on the inputs
  output$result <- renderPrint({
    inputs <- lapply(1:counter(), function(i) {
      inputId <- paste0("input", i)
      input[[inputId]]
    })
    paste("Inputs:", paste(inputs, collapse = ", "))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I update the code so the inputs are only printed when I click calculate?

Answer (score 1):

Use `bindEvent`:

```r
  output$result <- renderPrint({
    inputs <- lapply(1:counter(), function(i) {
      inputId <- paste0("input", i)
      input[[inputId]]
    })
    paste("Inputs:", paste(inputs, collapse = ", "))
  }) |> bindEvent(input$calculate)
```